# Copy XAMPP WordPress to sub-directory does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, subdirectory

I've set up WordPress in XAMPP for testing.  The main working site is:

localhost/wordpress

So I created a sub-directory called "gulf-mexico" after "wordpress" so it looks like:

localhost/wordpress/gulf-mexico

I then copied all of the files inside of the "wordpress" folder into "gulf-mexico" and then I went to:

localhost/wordpress/gulf-mexico/wp-admin

to get into it.  I typed the same credentials and it doesn't work so then i looked at:

localhost/wordpress/gulf-mexico

in the browser and got a 404.  I was under the impression you could do it this way but obviously not.  can someone help explain to me what else i need to do to get this "gulf-mexico" XAMPP site working?

thanks.

Comment: you also need some config and db settings changes

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

There are different scenarios when moving WordPress installation to different location/server. It's part of migration, so simply moving the files won't work. You need to carefully change your config settings, very often edit your .htaccess file and on top of that modify your database entries.

In your case, these 3 steps should do the job

1) Open your wp-config.php file and change the path location. Pay extra attention to / at the end of the path and location. If it's there - keep it, if not - don't include it.

2) Open your .htaccess file (if exists) and do exactly the same, change the path to have that extra folder

3) Go to your database (if you have phpmyadmin you can use it) and change all paths and locations again. You don't need to do it manually, you can perform SQL queries. For example:

```
update `table` set column='new value' where column='old value'
```

I will advice you to backup your existing database before doing any changes, you can always go back to original setup if something goes wrong.

For more information about migrating your WP install, check this official page:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: @deaf-guy - if you want to reply to my post, please add comment, there's no need to edit this answer if you want to add your feedback. Also make sure you approve the answer as correct if it solved your problem.